# Get an array/list from hashes values (within Hash)

Tags: ruby, hash

Since I would like to do some stats on `response_time` I'm looking for a simple way to get all `response_time` in an array or a list in order to compute average response time, median value, etc. As a Ruby beginner I'm always stuck when a Hash contains many hashes.

```
{
    0 => {
      :name => "log_endpoint",
      :response_time => "18"
    },   
    1 => {
      :name => "auth_endpoint"
      :response_time => "16"
    },
    2 => {
      :name => "get_friends_endpoint"
      :response_time => "16"
    },
    3 => {
      :name => "get_friends_endpoint"
      :response_time => "10"
    },
    4 => {
      :name => "log_endpoint",
      :response_time => "14"
    }
}
```

Thank you again for your help,

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your hash is called `stats`, you can simply do:

```
response_times = stats.values.map{ |s| s[:response_time] }
```

This iterates through all values in the outer hash and collects the `:respnose_time` from all the inner hashes.

Here it is in action: http://ideone.com/NwOTIg

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collect` on each value of your hash to gather what you want into an array. Assuming your hash is called `information`, `information.values` will give you an array of each value in `information` then calling collect on that array, will add each element with the given criteria into an array:

```
array_of_stuff = information.values.collect{ |info| info[:response_time] }
```

Note: I saw w0lf posted an answer which is very similar. As far as I know, map and collect would do the same thing, I just think collect sounds more logical in this case.